# Chaincode docker devmode cli error

Tags: docker, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am using the tutorial [Chaincode for Developers](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html) and I am getting an error while running "docker-compose-simple.yaml" file.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: One reason for BAD_REQUEST is that you already have a channel with that specific name. Can you try to remove all the containers via `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)` and start over again?

Comment: Hi! I have reset my docker multiple times and downloaded the images again. I am still getting this same issue.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the instructions mentioned in [Hyperledger Fabric Samples](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html) like

> If you are using Docker for Mac, you will need to use a location under /Users, /Volumes, /private, or /tmp. To use a different location, please consult the Docker documentation for file sharing.

I had some problem when I was using different directory.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I was able to complete this using a different method of deployment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you are using the **latest version** of Fabric (I assume that because you are reading the latest fabric.docs).
Clone the **1.0.0-beta version**, follow the instructions on 1.0.0-beta fabric docs and you'll be ok.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. I was able to complete this using a different method of deployment. Thanks!